# jboss war deploy : Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect

Tags: jboss

I try to deploy a war but I get this Exception :

> Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to
>   DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not
>   set","jboss.persistenceunit ...
>   => "org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

Answer (score 0):

Add following property in your hibernate config xml file

```
  <property name = "hibernate.dialect">
     org.hibernate.dialect.<DB_DRIVER>
  </property>
```

Comment: Here the possible dialect values: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6/html/development_guide/hibernate_sql_dialects1